# Convergence of multiple series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2+m^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

I have a following series

$$
\sum\frac{1}{n^2+m^2}
$$

As far as I understand it converges. I tried Cauchy criteria and it showed divergency, but i may be mistaken.

When I calculate it in matlab or Maxima it have a good behaviour and converge to finite number about 10.17615092535112.

The convergency plot is following:

[image]

Comment: Over which $n$ and $m$ do you take the sum? All $n$, $m$? Are they independent? I think then the series diverges...

Comment: Just to make sure (since I have no experience with matlab etc.) what does it give you for the series $\sum\frac 1n$?

Comment: thanks you, Simon, $\frac 1n$ also do not go to infinity and stay at really low values, like 12.09 at $10^5$ terms. That very strange.

Comment: That's what I expected. This has something to do with machine accuracy. Your computer can only represent numbers down to a certain number of digits. Hence for your computer the harmonic series is finite.

Comment: I bet you can even "show" that the harmonic series is constant after finitely many steps

Comment: I checked in matlab: $1/n$ diverges and 2D case $1/(n^2 + m^2)$ converges.

Comment: yep, this is something with machine accuracy, but nevertheless, those series have "logarithmic" divergency speed.

Comment: See also: [How to prove $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=+\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851302)

Answer (score 5):

Just to give an answer. The series diverges since
$$\frac{1}{n^2+m^2}\geq \frac{1}{(n+m)^2}$$ and therefore
$$\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{n^2+m^2}\geq \sum_{n,m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{(n+m)^2}.$$
For the RHS we have
$$\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb N}\frac{1}{(n+m)^2}=\sum_k\sum_{n+m=k}\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum_k\frac{k-1}{k^2}\sim\sum_k\frac{1}{k}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Matlabs sum for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{10^5} \frac{1}{n}$ is actually quite spot on, it's not a fault of machine accuracy. The series is called the [Harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) and is known to diverge very slowly. In fact, it behaves approximately like $\gamma + \ln n$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, about $0.57721.$ At $n=10^5$ we indeed expect about $0.57721 + 5\ln 10 \approx 12.0901.$

Matlab is also not saying anything incorrect for the original series, its results were just interpreted incorrectly (in a similar way to the previous example). The sum grows quite slowly. Consider if we order the sum like this: $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}.$$

By Residue Calculus methods, one can show that the inner sum is equal to $$ \frac{\pi m \coth(\pi m) -1}{2m^2}.$$

$\coth$ tends to $1$ exponentially quickly so one expects $$\sum_{m=1}^k \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2} \approx \frac{\pi \ln k}{2} + \frac{6\gamma \pi-\pi^2}{12}$$ for large $k.$

Comment: "By Residue Calculus methods, one can show that the inner sum is equal to": can you tell me where I can see the proof.

Comment: @Nothingspecial See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/991110/14657).