# $ \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|m+in|^p}<\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I need some help with this problem:

$$
\text{If} \;p>2 \Longrightarrow \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|m+in|^p}<\infty
$$

Note that [$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|m+in|^2}=\infty$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851302/how-to-prove-sum-m-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-frac1m2n2-infty?rq=1)

$|m+in|^2=m^2+n^2$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^{m^2+n^2\leq R^2} \dfrac1{(m^2+n^2)^{p/2}} < \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq R^2} \dfrac{dxdy}{(x^2+y^2)^{p/2}} = \int_{r=0}^R\int_{t = 0}^{2 \pi} \dfrac{rdrdt}{r^p} = 2\pi \int_{r=0}^R \dfrac{dr}{r^{p-1}}$$
Now conclude what you want.

You can also show that $p>2$ is necessary by lower-bounding
$$\sum_{m,n=1}^{m^2+n^2\leq R^2} \dfrac1{(m^2+n^2)^{p/2}} > \iint_{x^2+y^2 \geq 1}^{x^2+y^2 \leq R^2} \dfrac{dxdy}{(x^2+y^2)^{p/2}} = \int_{r=1}^R\int_{t = 0}^{2 \pi} \dfrac{rdrdt}{r^p} = 2\pi \int_{r=1}^R \dfrac{dr}{r^{p-1}}$$