# The double series $\sum\frac{1}{j^2+k^2}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

I want to show that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{j,k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2+k^2}}$ diverges.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have that $(j+k)^2=j^2+2jk+k^2\geq j^2+k^2$.

We get that \begin{equation*}(j+k)^2\geq k^2+j^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{k^2+j^2}\geq \frac{1}{(j+k)^2}\end{equation*}

We rearrange the series and we get \begin{equation*}\sum_{j,k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j^2+k^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j+k=m}\frac{1}{j^2+k^2}\end{equation*}

Then we have the following: 
\begin{align*}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j+k=m}\frac{1}{j^2+k^2}&\geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j+k=m}\frac{1}{(j+k)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j+k=m}\frac{1}{m^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}\cdot \sum_{j+k=m}1 \\ & =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}\cdot (m-1)\end{align*} since there are $m-1$ terms in the sum $\sum_{j+k=m}$ (these are the pairs $(1, m-1), (2, m-2), \ldots (m-1, 1)$).

So, we have that \begin{equation*}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j+k=m}\frac{1}{j^2+k^2}\geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2}\cdot (m-1)\end{equation*}

Is everything correct so far? How could we continue?

Comment: A [search in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bj%5E2%2Bk%5E2%7D%24&p=1) returns this question:
[How to prove $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=+\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851302)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=+\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851302/how-to-prove-sum-m-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-frac1m2n2-infty)