# How to look up the value of a convergent sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I would like to know if the value of the following double summation has been calculated:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2 + n^2}.$$

Any suggestions on how to look up such things in general? Is there a go-to dictionary for these sort of things?

Thanks

Comment: [How to prove $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=+\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851302/how-to-prove-sum-m-1-infty-sum-n-1-infty-frac1m2n2-infty)

Comment: Typing the sum into WolframAlpha can give a good indication in many cases.

Comment: Look them up via approachzero. All the common sums will be on this site already.

Comment: oh... it doesn't converge... silly me!